# Hibernate Search Sync strategy with Inheritance

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-search

I have a Spring boot project with 3 entities, UserEntity which is a standalone and Person which is inherited by lawyer.

I set the automatic indexing strategy to sync, When I insert a new user into the database, the new user is picked immediately, but a new lawyer or person are indexed but the don't appear in the result until I restart the mass indexer.

UserEntity:

```java
@Entity
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@Indexed
@SyncAnnotation(convertor = UserConvertor.class, repoClass = UserDetailServiceImplementation.class)
public class UserEntity implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "user_name", length = 20)
    @Basic
    private String username;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email")
    @Email
    private String email;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "full_name", length = 50, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "nvarchar(50)")
    @NotNull
    @FullTextField(termVector = TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS)
    private String fullName;
```

PersonEntity:

```java
@Entity
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "person_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
@Indexed
@SyncAnnotation(convertor = ClientConvertor.class, repoClass = PersonRepository.class)
public class PersonEntity implements Serializable {

    public PersonEntity(){
        this.personType=1;
    }
    
    @Id
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;
    
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 50, columnDefinition = "nvarchar(50)")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 50, columnDefinition = "nvarchar(50)")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "father_name", length = 50, columnDefinition = "nvarchar(50)")
    private String fatherName;

@Basic
@FullTextField(termVector = TermVector.YES)
@Column(name = "full_name", columnDefinition = "as concat(first_name,' ',isnull(father_name,''),' ',last_name)", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String fullName;

@Basic
@Column(name = "person_type", insertable = false, updatable = false)

@GenericField
private Integer personType;
```

And a LawyerEntity that inherits PersonEntity:

```java
@Entity
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
@Indexed
@SyncAnnotation(convertor = ClientConvertor.class, repoClass = LawyerRepository.class)
public class LawyerEntity extends PersonEntity {

        public LawyerEntity(){
                this.setPersonType(2);
        }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "bar_id")
    @GenericField
    private Integer barId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "bar_card_number")
    private Long barCardNumber;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "bar_regisration_date")
    private LocalDate barRegistrationDate;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = BarEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_lawyer_bar"),
            name = "bar_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private BarEntity bar;
}
```

When using `Sync` hibernate search automatic indexing strategy, the UserEntity index updates and includes the newly inserted entities in the index , the TRACE output:

```
2022-12-22 10:16:06.112 TRACE 68869 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] i.AfterCommitIndexingPlanSynchronization : Processing Transaction's beforeCompletion() phase for org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl@5193eb5f.
2022-12-22 10:16:06.119 TRACE 68869 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] i.AfterCommitIndexingPlanSynchronization : Processing Transaction's afterCompletion() phase for org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl@5193eb5f. Executing indexing plan.
2022-12-22 10:16:06.119 TRACE 68869 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.s.e.b.o.spi.SingletonTask            : Scheduling task 'Lucene indexing orchestrator for index 'User' - 9'.
2022-12-22 10:16:06.120 TRACE 68869 --- [rker thread - 2] o.h.s.e.b.o.spi.SingletonTask            : Running task 'Lucene indexing orchestrator for index 'User' - 9'
2022-12-22 10:16:06.120 TRACE 68869 --- [rker thread - 2] o.h.s.e.b.o.spi.BatchingExecutor         : Processing 1 works in executor 'Lucene indexing orchestrator for index 'User' - 9'
2022-12-22 10:16:06.132 TRACE 68869 --- [rker thread - 2] o.h.s.e.b.o.spi.BatchingExecutor         : Processed 1 works in executor 'Lucene indexing orchestrator for index 'User' - 9'
2022-12-22 10:16:06.132 TRACE 68869 --- [rker thread - 2] o.h.s.e.b.o.spi.SingletonTask            : Completed task 'Lucene indexing orchestrator for index 'User' - 9'
```

However, when entering a new person or a lawyer, the index doesn't reflect the changes, not even after awhile, I need to restart the massindexer for it work, it has  a similar output to the previous log, but it doesn't reflect the changes on the index until I restart the mass indexer

```
2022-12-22 10:14:38.086 TRACE 68869 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] i.AfterCommitIndexingPlanSynchronization : Processing Transaction's beforeCompletion() phase for org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl@6b9d9f5e.
2022-12-22 10:14:38.089 TRACE 68869 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] i.AfterCommitIndexingPlanSynchronization : Processing Transaction's afterCompletion() phase for org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl@6b9d9f5e. Executing indexing plan.
2022-12-22 10:14:38.091 TRACE 68869 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.s.e.b.o.spi.SingletonTask            : Scheduling task 'Lucene indexing orchestrator for index 'Person' - 8'.
2022-12-22 10:14:38.091 TRACE 68869 --- [rker thread - 3] o.h.s.e.b.o.spi.SingletonTask            : Running task 'Lucene indexing orchestrator for index 'Person' - 8'
2022-12-22 10:14:38.092 TRACE 68869 --- [rker thread - 3] o.h.s.e.b.o.spi.BatchingExecutor         : Processing 1 works in executor 'Lucene indexing orchestrator for index 'Person' - 8'
2022-12-22 10:14:38.137 TRACE 68869 --- [rker thread - 3] o.h.s.e.b.o.spi.BatchingExecutor         : Processed 1 works in executor 'Lucene indexing orchestrator for index 'Person' - 8'
2022-12-22 10:14:38.138 TRACE 68869 --- [rker thread - 3] o.h.s.e.b.o.spi.SingletonTask            : Completed task 'Lucene indexing orchestrator for index 'Person' - 8'
```

How can I make it detect show the change in the index without restart mass index ?
I also tried calling hibernate search indexing plan but to no success

I am using Hibernate search 6.1.6.Final with lucene backend and spring boot 2.7.5

As per request:
The code used to search for UserEntity (user can belong to bar):

```java
    public List<UserEntity> findInAnyRole(String name, Integer barId, UUID[] role) {
        var session = sessionProvider.getSearchSession();
        var search = session.search(UserEntity.class);
        var res = search.where(f -> f.bool(
                b -> {
                    b.must(f.match().field("fullName").matching(name).fuzzy(2));
                    if (role != null && role.length > 0) {
                        b.must(f.bool(b2 -> {
                            for (var roleValue : role)
                                b2.should(f.match().field("roles.id").matching(roleValue));
                        }));
                    }
                    if (barId != null)
                        b.must(f.match().field("barId").matching(barId));
                }
        ));
        return res.fetchHits(10);
    }
```

As for PersonEntity:

```java
    public List<PersonEntity> findSimilar(@NotNull String name, String[] ids) {
        var session = sessionProvider.getSearchSession();
        var search = session.search(PersonEntity.class);
        var q=search.where(f -> f.bool().must(f.match().field("fullName").matching(name).fuzzy(2))
                .must(f.match().field("personType").matching(1))).sort(searchSortFactory -> searchSortFactory.score().desc());
        log.info(q.toQuery().queryString());
        return q.fetchHits(10);
    }
```

and LawyerEntity:

```java
    public List<LawyerEntity> findSimilar(@NotNull String name, Integer barId) {
        var session = sessionProvider.getSearchSession();
        var search = session.search(LawyerEntity.class);
        var res = search.where(f -> f.match().field("fullName").matching(name).fuzzy(2));
        if (barId != null)
            res = search.where(f -> f.bool().must(f.match().field("fullName").matching(name).fuzzy(2))
                    .must(f.match().field("barId").matching(barId)));
        var list = res.fetchHits(10);
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, indexing seems to work fine (judging from the logs). Please share the code you use to check the content of the index?

Comment: That's the whole point, it's driving me crazy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem is here:

```
@Column(name = "full_name", columnDefinition = "as concat(first_name,' ',isnull(father_name,''),' ',last_name)", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String fullName;
```

As you're defining the full name on the database side, it will only be populated correctly when it's loaded from the database. The first time you create your entity, or anytime you change the first name or last name on your Java object, the `fullName` property in your Java object will not have the correct value, until it's loaded back from the database.

I think that when you create your entity, `fullName` is `null`, so Hibernate Search is indexing your entities with a `fullName` index field set to `null`, which explains that your queries (with predicates on the `fullName` field) do not match anything.

When you use the mass indexer, on the other hand, entities are loaded from the database and `fullName` is populated correctly from the database.

As to solutions, either:

- Always update `fullName` manually whenever you update `firstName` or `lastName`. That might be inconvenient.
- OR, if you don't need to use `fullName` in SQL queries, do not persist `fullName` in the database, do not add a `fullName` property to your entity, and just declare a `getFullName()` getter annotated with `@javax.persistence.Transient` that does the concatenation in Java:

  ```java
  @Transient
  @FullTextField(termVector = TermVector.YES)
  @IndexingDependency(derivedFrom = {
      @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = "firstName")),
      @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = "fatherName")),
      @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = "lastName"))
  })
  public String getFullName() {
    return firstName
        + ( fatherName == null ? "" : " " + fatherName )
        + " " + lastName;
  }
  ```

  See [this section of the documentation for `@IndexingDependency`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-reindexing-derivedfrom).

Comment: I suspected as much, It is a calculated field after all. I will try and let you know

Comment: I ended up converting the full_name field to a normal field instead of computed one while keeping the values thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143867/convert-computed-column-to-regular-column